# Condition for a polynomial invariant ring to be a UFD

Tags: invariant-theory

Let $W$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over $%
%TCIMACRO{\U{2102} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{C}
%EndExpansion
$. Let $\rho $ $:G\rightarrow $ GL$(W)$ be a representation of any finite
group $G$. How can we show that if all characters of $G$ are trivial then $%
%TCIMACRO{\U{2102} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{C}
%EndExpansion
\lbrack W]^{G}$ is a UFD? I know there is a proof in one of Benson's books,
but I'm finding it quite hard to follow.

Also, I'm stuck on the following: By considering a representation of $C_{2}$
show that a polynomial invariant ring can fail to be a unique factorisation
domain, even in characteristic zero.

Thank you.